# Calculating specific cells based on cell condition

Tags: python, pandas, excel, if-statement

I have:

EXCEL 1:

```
NAME   Year  ACTIVITY     AMOUNT
AA      1        CC          140
AA      1        CC          150
AA      1        DD          80
```

My desired output is:

```
NAME   ACTIVITY  YEAR   TOTAL AMOUNT
AA      CC        1      290
AA      DD        1       80
```

So output will calculate the total amount based on the variables as shown above (it has to have the same conditions so total amount can be summed):

```
search_1 = 'AA'
search_2 = '1'
search_3 = 'CC'

for i in range (0,length):
    if search_1 == Name [i]:
        if YEAR[i] == search_2:
            if ACTIVITY[i] == search_3:
     
                    TOTAL AMOUNT[i] == print(sum(df ['Amount']))
```

The problem is, it keeps on counting the total "Amount" column, even if they have different year (result becomes 370). anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Lets filter the data and then group by the proper columns and aggregate the data by summing the 'AMOUNT' column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

search_1 = 'AA'
search_2 = 1
search_3 = 'CC'

filtered_df = df[(df['NAME'] == search_1) & (df['Year'] == search_2) & (df['ACTIVITY'] == search_3)]

grouped_df = filtered_df.groupby(['NAME', 'ACTIVITY', 'Year'])['AMOUNT'].sum().reset_index()

grouped_df.rename(columns={'AMOUNT': 'TOTAL AMOUNT'}, inplace=True)

print(grouped_df)
```